# How to test Login error validation python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I need to test Login page validation.  If the user doesn't enter username, then the formErrorContent need to show beside the username.

This is what I did

```
    def test_UserNameValidate(self):
    self.driver.getElement("id", "user").click()
    self.driver.getElement("id", "password").click()
    user = self.driver.getElement("id", "user")
    try:
       error_user = user.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-usr"]/div/div[@class="formErrorContent"]')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        error_user = None
```

This test is passing. I got the try and except method from web and changed for my condition.  I'm not sure I'm doing right validation. Also, I didn't understand whats going on Try and except.  Can someone help to solve this puzzle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `try except` your script will fail in case of no error message disappear (`try except` 'ignore' NoSuchElementException). You should also write assertion to check if message is present, because if you use `try except` the test will always pass.